# Volume in the Charts is different than what gets returned from the API's

Tags: charts, bittrex, volume

when I pull volume data (BaseVolume?) from the Bittrex (for example) API every minute, draw a chart from that data and then compare that with the one minute timeframed volume chart (the study chart) on Bittrex it looks totally different.

I used BaseVolume, but i also tried to draw graphs with any other field that gets returned and I can't seem to replace these charts at all with any value. Does anyone have any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear which API call that you are using so I'll give my two ideas on what the problem might be:

1. If you are using the "getmarketsummary" API call and calling that
   every minute then you will get wrong data because this is based on
   24-hours. In my opinion, this is a useless feature.
2. If you are getting the market trades and then calculating the OHLCV
   value in 1-minute periods, and those values don't match up with the
   Bittrex candle charts then you are probably seeing the 2 to 4 minute
   delay that Bittrex has. I use a service ([ClueDex](https://www.cluedex.com/api)) that removes
   that delay and I can literally get 1-minute OHLCV candle data as
   soon as the minute closes.